# angular ng-autocomplete does not set initial value if is in a form

Tags: angular

I'm using ng autocomplete in a project and it is all working fine.
Today I have found an issue and I cannot find a workaround.

basically, if the autocomplete is inside a reactive form, the property "initialValue" does not work.
I've searched on the internet but I have not found anything helpful.

I've created a stackblitz that demonstrates my issue: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-crrlnv

I will be more than happy if anyone can help me?

Thanks in advance.

Edit: find a workaround with patchValue, but if I had to set another value after a backend call, the patchValue doesnt work... weird...

Comment: Ps. I already tried the setValue() with no luck

Answer (score 1):

You gave your first formControl inside formGroup a default value of an empty string: (so you have collision with ng-autocomplete initial value and formControl initial value)

```
 this.providerForm = this.fb.group({
      test: ['']

    });
```

change it to:

```
test: this.initialValue.name
```

and initial value will work (your can remove initial value of ng-autocomplete).

Comment: thanks for your response but is not what I mean. In the real app, I have a backend call and after the response I have to initialize the field. But testing some solution I found that patchValue works, but only if I set the autocomplete value. If I set another field, the autocomplete stops working. really weird

Comment: No problem.
I'm not sure i understand 100%, I tried to use patchValue in ngOnInit (in your example you assigned a value for formControl in the constructor) and it worked. 
Also tried to assign a value to a new field with pathValue and it worked and auto complete kept working.

Comment: @Davide.77 as zohar said, just use : `this.providerForm.get('test').patchValue(this.initialValue.name) ` when you get the data from the server. also remove the `initiavalue=...` property from `ng-autocomplete`, since you're binding a form control to it. you can see it here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-kffpc4?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html